# Aligning equal signs in align environment

Tags: vertical-alignment, align, amsmath

[image]Is it possible to align the second equal sign to the fourth? So I want to have space in front of the second equal sign, so that all equal signs are pairwise aligned. The code is the following

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    (dx_1)^2&=d(r\cos\xi)^2=(\cos\xi dr-r\sin\xi d\xi)^2\\
    (dx_i)^2&=d(r\omega_i\sin\xi)^2=(\omega_i\sin\xi dr+r\omega_i\cos\xi d\xi+r\sin\xi d\omega_i)^2
 \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with `alignat`:

**edit:**
corrected position of ampersands, as suggested [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) in his comment

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
(dx_1)^2 & = d(r\cos\xi)^2         && = (\cos\xi dr-r\sin\xi d\xi)^2\\
(dx_i)^2 & = d(r\omega_i\sin\xi)^2 && = (\omega_i\sin\xi dr+r\omega_i\cos\xi d\xi+r\sin\xi d\omega_i)^2
 \end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or with `array`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\[\setlength\arraycolsep{1pt}
\begin{array}{rll}
(dx_1)^2 & = d(r\cos\xi)^2         & = (\cos\xi dr-r\sin\xi d\xi)^2\\
(dx_i)^2 & = d(r\omega_i\sin\xi)^2 & = (\omega_i\sin\xi dr+r\omega_i\cos\xi d\xi+r\sin\xi d\omega_i)^2
 \end{array}
 \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**addedndum:**
many people are strict in distinguishing between variables (italic shape) and operators (roman shape). this convention is supported by the package `physics` (and others) and consider in the first two equations in the next example.

if you prefer to have operator `d` in italic shape, than it is usual emphasize with small space before it (see second two equations). for this you can define new command, for example :

```
\newcommand{\df}{\mathop{}\!d}
```

as suggested [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{physics}

\newcommand{\df}{\mathop{}\!d}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
(\dd x_1)^2 & = \dd(r\cos\xi)^2         && = (\cos\xi \dd r-r\sin\xi \dd \xi)^2\\
(\dd x_i)^2 & = \dd(r\omega_i\sin\xi)^2 && = (\omega_i\sin\xi \dd r+r\omega_i\cos\xi \dd \xi+r\sin\xi \dd \omega_i)^2
 \end{alignat*}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
(\df x_1)^2 & = \df(r\cos\xi)^2         && = (\cos\xi \df r-r\sin\xi \df \xi)^2\\
(\df x_i)^2 & = \df(r\omega_i\sin\xi)^2 && = (\omega_i\sin\xi \df r+r\omega_i\cos\xi \df \xi+r\sin\xi \df \omega_i)^2
 \end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wrong spacing around the second `=` sign. You just need `{alignat*}{2}` and to write `&&=` instead of `&=&`

Comment: @egreg, i notice this. i will look, what i miss.

Comment: @egreg, thank you for tip. i'm not very familiar with `alignat` ... corrected now!

Comment: I'd also recommend to change all differential d into `\df` after giving the definition `\newcommand{\df}{\mathop{}\!d}` that will nicely space the differential when needed.

Comment: well, this improvement is for extra bonus. i will add this to answer too asap